# how to add xtick and xtick label in matlab without changing the rest of the automatic ticks and ticklabels

Tags: matlab

I want to mark some special point on the x-axis of a matlab plot, and I'm satisfied with the rest automatic x-ticks that matlab produce. Therefore I do not want to change them, only to add this special xtick and xticklabel in the midst of them. What is the easiest way to do it in a matlab m-function?

Comment: This comes to mind: using the `text` function you can plot text anywhere in the plot. And using `patch` you could *erase* the current tick at that particular place. This is a crazy workaround and if you need something "more professional" then wait for other answers :-).

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
plot(1:100);
ticks = get(gca,'XTick');
ticklabels = cellstr(get(gca,'XTickLabel'));
ticks(end+1) = pi;
ticklabels{end+1} = 'Pi';
[ticks,idx] = sort(ticks);
ticklabels = ticklabels(idx);
set(gca,'Xtick',ticks,'XTickLabel',ticklabels);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
plot(1:5,1:5)
marks = get(gca,'XTick');
marks = sort([marks,pi]);
set(gca,'XTick',marks);
```

There are some issues with scaleability, calling xlim, etc. but maybe it is good enough for your problem.